# how to retrieve javascript response in loadrunner 11 version

Tags: loadrunner

I'm using loadrunner 11 and did scripting for SOAp services. My response is coming in javascript.

**sample response**

```
function buildView() { ("testpage_soap_response");
  var xmlString = '<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header/><env:Body><IssueQuoteProcessResponse xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/IssueQuoteProcess" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/IssueQuoteProcess"><ns0:Header><ns0:Status>false<\/ns0:Status><ns0:Message/><\/ns0:Header><ns0:Data><ns0:URL>http://insurance.nic.co.in/insurance/pub/workflow/TaskOperateUICAction.do?procName=NewBiz Process&amp;taskName=NewBiz Quotation&amp;taskId=390290815&amp;toOwnUrl=true<\/ns0:URL><ns0:ID>AABB<\/ns0:ID><ns0:CUSTOMER_NAME>jklff<\/ns0:CUSTOMER_NAME><\/ns0:Data><\/IssueQuoteProcessResponse><\/env:Body><\/env:Envelope>' responseArea.value = xmlString
```

I need to capture AABB value.we can do these using web_js_run but it is not supported by loadrunner 11. Any other way to get javascript response in loadrunner11.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the web_reg_save_param_ex API before your web_service_call to save the AABB into parameter.

web_reg_save_param_ex(const char* ParamName, const char* LB, const char* RB, string List of Attributes, string SEARCH FILTERS, string LAST);